# Perl Syntaxcheck: Add path

Tags: vim, syntastic

Some perl modules i'm using are not in any directory in my $PATH, but in another. Normaler, I have to do

```
use lib '/path/to/modules';
use ModuleOne;
```

in order to use it. Or, if I do it on the terminal

```
perl -I/path/to/modules ....
```

But since we're using Perl-Modules in our Apache, the Apache does include the directory. So we do not have to write `use lib...` every time.

Syntastic does not know this, and marks all `use`s of such modules as syntax-errors.

Is there any way to tell syntastic to add another Directory to the path when syntax-checking, similar to the `perl -I`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to `g:syntastic_perl_lib_path`:

```
let g:syntastic_perl_lib_path = ['/some/lib', '/some/other/lib' ]
```

This is documented in the [wiki](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Perl%3A---perl).