# Is there a way to tell syntastic which library to use to avoid @INC errors

Tags: perl, vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

I'm editing a test file which is typically run with `prove -l` which automatically includes the `lib` directory when searching for packages to load. When editing the file, [vim-syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) reports it can't find the needed packages because it is not looking in the `lib` directory.

Is there a way to tell `syntastic` to include the `lib` directory in the @INC so I can avoid the `Can't locate Blah::Blah.pm in @INC` error without having to do `use lib 'lib'` at the top of my file?

Comment: Please check my edits (link and tags), as I had to guess a little

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl Syntaxcheck: Add path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486762/perl-syntaxcheck-add-path)

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer. Place following in `.vimrc` file:

`let g:syntastic_perl_lib_path = ['lib' ]`

From: [Perl Syntaxcheck: Add path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486762/perl-syntaxcheck-add-path)

Comment: If only there was something like, you know, a manual, documenting all these arcane variables...  Oh, wait, never mind.

Comment: It's actually not in the documentation in vim. I read through it. It's in a wiki I had no idea existed.

Comment: The contents of the wiki has been included in the manual years ago.  Try `:h syntastic-perl-perl`.

Comment: That doesn't help me know that it existed either. Nothing in :h syntastic would let me know that help file even existed. You can't read documentation you don't know exists.

Comment: From the "Intro" section in the help: _Take a look at the list of supported filetypes and checkers: `syntastic-checkers`._

Comment: That's about as clear as mud where I can find the help. So I guess when reading documentation I can no longer rely on scanning it but I need to pore through everything the documentation says in order uncover hidden settings in obscure sections of the documentation. Clearly, this is not helpful. Your position is clearly indefensible.

Comment: Much better would be, in the Intro, in bold and in color: This documentation covers only the core syntastic plugin. For documentation on language-specific syntax checkers use :help syntastic-<language>-<language>.